# How to boot Android sims via Android Debug Bridge

Tags: android, android-studio

Don't see my sims with `adb devices` unless they're booted.

Is there a way to boot sims I can't see from adb?

Thanks

Comment: "sims"? You mean Android Smartphone(s)? Why have you added the android-studio tag?